# Javascript - Check incoming object for embedded array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to create a function to check if a person has voted on a deal.

When the user votes on a deal their name is added to the voters array.

Basically i would like check if the incoming deal objects, voters array contains the logged in user

How can i check this?

Function

```
    $scope.upVoteHome = function(deal) {

    if(XXXXXX){

        // User has not voted already.

    }else{

        deal.votes++;
        deal.voters.push(user);
        deal.$update(function() {
            //$location.path('deals/' + deal._id);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            // rollback votes on fail also
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    }



};
```

The Deal Model

```
    var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: 'NA',
        required: 'Please fill Item title',
        trim: true
    },
    voters: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
$scope.upVoteHome = function(deal) {

    var hasVoted = deal.voters.filter(function(voter) {
        return voter.ref == $scope.loggedInUser;
    }).length > 0;

    if(!hasVoted) {

        // User has not voted already.

    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks.